# How can you define a for loop's outcome in an if and else statement (in python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

My code may look confusing, so I will go step by step. Here is what I have done (that works):

I have a 6 lists. My code asks the user how many items are in the user's cart. It takes that number and prints that number of random items selected from the lists (e.g. If a user enters `4` for `items in cart`, this random list of cart items might be generated: `['pineapple', 'iPhone case', 'toolbox', 'olives']`).

**My question:**
How can I define the random item lists so if `'pineapple'` is printed it would add 1 to the bill?

```
items_1 =[ "soap","ketchup","pineapple","crisp","twix"]
items_2  = ["olives","mouse pad","shampoo","coke","ruler","pen"]
items_3 =  ["honey","mirror","chocolate bar","fanta"]
items_4 = ["candle","doughnuts","pencil","dr pepper","broccoli","cabbage"]
items_5 = ["book","butter","jam","umbrella","toolbox","knife"]
items_6 = [ "tissue","iphone case","jewels","sprite"]
list_of_lists = [items_1, items_2, items_3, items_4, items_5, items_6]
item_cart=int(input("how many items in the cart"))
scan10=(random.choice(random.choice(list_of_lists)))

for scan in range(item_cart):
     scan1=print(random.choice(random.choice(list_of_lists)))

#BillCreating
print("here are your items")
bill=0

if "soap" in scan1: 
   bill+1
if "ketchup" in scan1: 
   bill+1
if "pineapple" in scan1: 
   bill+1
if "crisp" in scan1: 
   bill+1
if "twix" in scan1: 
   bill+1



print("total:",(bill))
```

Comment: I&#39;m a little in the dark about what you want to do, but if i read you correctly you should replace all the bill+1 with bill =+1. That will increase your bill count if one of your specified items are returned from the random calls. And the print statement will probably crash since you mix str and int types. Replace it with print("total: {}".format(bill)).

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, your comment has increased my bill count which is a first for me :) however,how many items in the cart12
pineapple
soap
dr pepper
crisp
shampoo
book
twix
ketchup
iphone case
mirror
tissue
coke
here are your items
total: 1 event though there is more items that are in if statement it still only formats bill as 1

Comment: precisely, I want everytime that a word from my if statements is called randomly to add 1 to the bill

Comment: Since all the items in your if clauses are in the first list I don't find that count too surprising. You select both a random list and a random items. Do you find that odd?

Comment: I do agree actually, now looking at it. how could I manipulate my code for if everytime any of the random calls are from items_1 it would add 1 to the bill. Thus, I could copy this for all of my lists

Comment: If you want to be sure about the behavior - add a print statement in you for loop. Simply just print out the scan1. But you main issue is that you need to indent the if-blocks and move the bill=0 up before the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bill=0

for i in range(item_cart):
    scan1=random.choice(random.choice(list_of_lists))
    if scan1 in ["twix", "pineapple",....]:
        bill+=1

print("here are your items")
print("total: {}".format(bill))
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged on stack overflow. Please consider editing to explain what you have done and why it works.

Comment: @Shadow - I agree. Since I I already did that as comments in my initial dialogue with the user, and since I was replying from a phone, I found that to be redundant in this case.

Comment: It's important to establish full context in the answer so that when people come to this page via google they can easily obtain all of the information needed to understand an answer fully. Remember this is QA site, not a forum. We're not trying to help this specific user - we're trying to help everyone with this problem.

Comment: Indeed we are. Thank you for helping me out on this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `+=`.

```
if "pineapple" in scan1: 
    bill += 1
```

IIUC, and you want the random `item_cart` items to be drawn from any of the 6 item lists, consider tightening up your code by flattening `list_of_lists` first, and then summing over all billable items.

In this approach, you don't need to worry about incrementing the `bill` count sequentially:

```
import numpy as np

item_list = [item for i_list in list_of_lists for item in i_list]
item_cart = int(input("how many items in the cart"))
scan1 = np.random.choice(item_list, size=item_cart)
billable_items = ["soap", "ketchup", "pineapple", "crisp", "twix"]

bill = sum([1 for b_item in billable_items if b_item in scan1])

print(f"here are your items: {scan1}")
print(f"total: {bill}")
```

If you can use Pandas, this gets even more compact:

```
import pandas as pd

bill = pd.Series(billable_items).isin(scan1).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

`bill+1` adds `bill` and `1` together - and then returns the result.

I expect you want bill to increase by one, in which case you would need to actually save the result

```
bill = bill + 1
```

Python (and many other languages) have a shorthand for doing this.

```
bill += 1
```